# ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrToRemove' of undefined

Tags: aurelia

I am using Aurelia to build single page application and I am getting an error during view loading for a new route:

> ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrToRemove' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you did not mistype any Aurelia attribute in your view template. (Ex `reapet.for` instead of `repeat.for`).